# Area with different unit measurements

Tags: area

What is the area of a rectangle, in square meters, with a length of 108 meters and a width of 300 millimeters?

I think it could be 324 sqm.

Answer (score 0):

Why "could" it be $324 \text{m}^2$?

$$108 \text{m} \cdot 300 \cdot 10^{-3}\text{m}=32.4\text{m}^2$$

Comment: How can it be less than 108 metres if there are 2 lengths of 108 metres with some space between them?

Comment: Well, that's a surface not a lenght. Take a $100'000\text{km}$ length with a $1\text{pm}$ width, the surface will be $1\text{mm}^2$. How is that a problem ? (you can also say : "wut how can it be more than $1\text{m}^2$ if there are 2 widths of $3\text{dm}$ with some space between them").